# Reproduce llvm IR type error programatically

Tags: c++, llvm, typeerror

By sheer chance, I ran llc on some code dumped from a **working** llvm backend. By working I mean, there is production-level code, that compiles this example successfully and the result executes correctly.

Here is a (shortened and abstracted) excerpt:

```
%s = type { i8* }

define double @foo(i8*) { ret double 0.0 }

@"foo" = constant %s { double (i8*)* @"foo" }
```

llc complains:

> error: element 0 of struct initializer doesn't match struct element
>   type

How do I trigger the same error with the C++ API? The verifyModules setting does not produce any error.

Answer (score 0):

llc is correct. Your struct has elements of type i8*, but your initializer has type (i8*)*, so you'd need explicit bitcast here. You could easily re-create the same code via C++ API, however, I believe you will receive an assert here with C++ API.